# Convert Entity Framework from Database First to Code First

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to convert an existing data model from Database First to Code First.

**Background**

The current solution (put in place before me) uses a Database project to define the model.  This is then published to a database, and we then update an EDMX model from said database.

Finally, a couple of T4 templates are run to generate POCO classes from the EDMX model, as well as the `DBContext`.

I want to get rid of this, and move purely to a Code First migration approach.

**What I've Done So Far**

- I have taken the POCO classes that were generated by the T4 template, and made them first class citizens of the project.
- I then removed the T4 template from the solution
- I took the DBContext that was generated by the T4 template, and also made it a first class citizen of the project.
- I then removed this T4 template from the solution
- From the Package Manager Console, I ran "Enable-Migrations", and it created my Migrations folder

I also changed the connection string to use the System.Data.SqlClient provider.
Was:

```
<add name="MyContext" connectionString="metadata=res://Project.Data/Model.MyModel.csdl|res://Project.Data/Model.MyModel.ssdl|res://Project.Data/Model.MyModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=MY-SERVER;initial catalog=MY-DB;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Changed to:

```
<add name="MyContext" connectionString="data source=MY-SERVER;initial catalog=MY-DB;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

**Here is where I am having an issue**

I am now trying to create the initial migration, passing the `-IgnoreChanges` flag so that I get an empty migration (given the age of the database, I want future migrations to be based off the current schema, and not create a migration from scratch).

When I run: `Add-Migration InitialCreate -IgnoreChanges`

I get this error:

> Unable to load the specified metadata resource.

When I run: `Add-Migration InitialCreate -IgnoreChanges -ConnectionString "data source=MY-SERVER;initial catalog=MY-DB;Integrated Security=SSPI;" -ConnectionStringProviderName "System.Data.SqlClient"`

I get this error:

> Can not override the connection for this context with a standard
>   DbConnection because the original connection was an EntityConnection.

At a loss here.  It appears that even though I've removed references to the EDMX model, the context still knows about it.  I'd like to get rid of it completely and go pure Code First.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Did you consider using Code First from Database? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj200620.aspx

Comment: That is the direction that I think we're going to have to go.  Given some...interesting use of table inheritance I was trying to avoid this (keep the baseline model in db only and have migrations as changes post this only).  I will look into this though.

Comment: I am using it now and it works pretty good. You will probably have a little trouble if the db does not follow the conventions expected by Entity Framework but there are ways around it. I found I had to manually create a couple of tables that EF needed to handle the includes.

Comment: Use the below link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591621(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: Have you tried out this walk through already?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/workflows/existing-database

In the first steps, it will let you create a sample database and then, in chapter 3 "Reverse Engineer Model" it gets interesting. Select "Code first from database" and follow along the steps.

Answer (score 1):

Just comment out the contents of the InitialCreate.cs
then run in PM

```
update-database
```

new migrations will work correctly after that.

Answer (score -2):

Ask the basic question: How many tables are in the database, and is it worth replacing a house of cards hodge-podge of build/deploy tools for another hodge-podge house of cards set of tools?

For a large 400+ table EF solution with similar custom build steps hacks, we replace it in stages with each product release.

We replaced the C# EF usage for a few tables at time with each release and eventually retired all of the third party build/deploy tools and old EF code.

Replace them in functional area chunks, with replacing usage of the tables in that functional area all at the same time.

We stopped using EF migrations as they cost more and more as time went on due to the complexity.

Comment: _We stopped using EF migrations as they cost more and more as time went on due to the complexity._... Sounds like you did things wrong. You also haven't mentioned what you replaced it with, so this is just an extended comment and doesn't directly address OP at all. Pro tip if anyone else has a similar experience, learn to re-base your migrations to specific versions.

Comment: App became covered by Sarbanes Oxley and needed all DB changes audited by the DBA.  Dba did not want to review the EF generated upgrade SQL scripts - too complex, generic auto generated schema change code.

Comment: Well more power to you, I routinely convert solutions over to using migrations specifically to reduce the schema change code and to gain control over it, perhaps the important aspect is that the schema logic is checked in with the rest of the source control. Each to our own I guess, but your response doesn't actually help OP solve their issue so the point is moot. I would have loved to help you sort through your issues before you lost faith in the tools ;)

Comment: We were disappointed in all of the extra work above and beyond just writing SQL schema change scripts when using Entity Framework.  EF got in the way of understanding the DB changes when anyone outside of our core C# back-end developers read the code.  EF migrations excluded our front-end developers, QA people, DBA team and others from easily seeing what database changes we were making and of note, we had to get those changes approved by the data owner group which didn't know C#, didn't want to see C# EF migration code and wanted SQL scripts.

Comment: Right so EF forces you to choose who has ownership of the schema. Code First Migrations means that the code "owns" the schema, which is usually important to the application runtimes that we build, DBAs making seemingly minor changes can break the whole app and wouldn't know, because they don't use the app. If you can't give ownership of the schema to the code, then it is not for your solution. You could hybrid approach it, by letting EF manage the application schema and lets DBAs go nuts on any other schema, but they'll just get in your way anyway ;)

Comment: So while your answer provides a different viewpoint, it is specific to your organisation's inability to embrace migrations as the _only_ mechanism to maintain the DB schema. If front end team needs schema and that doesn't involve the backend, aka EF, then you have other management issues to deal with. Code first migrations help simplify the schema management and tightly couple it to the codebase as a result. It's a trade off for sure, but one I gladly make to streamline and manage the application development.

Comment: Hi Chris.  I appreciate all the comments.  The database in question is used by multiple applications and owned by a data owner.  The data owner has final approval on schema changes.  We're one team and have to propose our changes and get approval of them.  The system in question is a financial one and is covered by government regulations requiring this level of approvals and inspection of any schema changes by SQL script.  Forcing each of the other teams, front-end devs for our app, DBAs to learn C# EF migrations would not work.  We have to review other teams schema changes too for Java apps.

Comment: This is common that other apps which came after ours did not want to depend on our API (different technology, longevity risk) to get at the database.  Our organization did SOA before and it fell down because you could not update any old SOA APIs once they got used by more than 3 applications because there was no budget or staff to retest / rebuild / upgrade those other applications every few months.  SOA worked OK when everything was disjoint and unconnected. Once the connections between apps started and grew to a mass spiderweb, changing anything was a blocker due to the retesting cost.

Comment: It important to identify the context of the OP, this was posted at a time when Code-First was being introduced, so for a while many EF teams were maintaining legacy EDMX based EF and were struggling to migrate over to pure Code First. I'm happy to provide consult on your solution as the issues you have identified, for me EF migrations is a solution for, not a hinderance, importantly it lowers the TCO, as long as you are happy to follow the rules ;). But that is out of scope for this post and I suspect you're happy where you are now.